# JAX-RS one mapper for all custom exceptions

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs

I've created a custom exception to notify user if something went wrong. E.g. if user send some not correct data from front-end and check for that is happening somewhere deep in back-end than all I need to do it just to

> throw new CustomException("Message", 406)

with message and error code. And after that will immediately send a response to front-end with error code and text message which I can show on UI e.g. as a snackbar.

**CustomException**

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

  private final int errorCode;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6220614065727287629L;


  public CustomException(String message, int errorCode) {
    super(message);
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
  }
}
```

**CustomExceptionMapper**

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CustomException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(CustomException ex) {

    ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage(), ex.getErrorCode());
    return Response.status(ex.getErrorCode()).entity(response).build();
  }
}
```

**ErrorResponse**

public class ErrorResponse {

```
 private Error error;

  ErrorResponse(String errorMessage, int errorCode) {
    createError(errorMessage, errorCode);
  }

  private void createError(String message, int code) {
    setError(new Error(message, code));
  }

  public Error getError() {
    return error;
  }

  public void setError(Error error) {
    this.error = error;
  }

}
```

**Error**

```
public class Error {
  private String message;
  private int code;

  public Error(String message, int code) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

But now I need some extra functionality. For form validation in back-end I need to send also which text field was not correct. So I think the best way to do that is to create a new child exception of CustomException and add there a new property.

**CustomFormException**

```
public class CustomFormException extends CustomException {

  private final String formField;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6220614065727287630L;


  public CustomFormException(String message, int errorCode, String formField) {
    super(message, errorCode);
    this.formField = formField;
  }

  String getFormField() {
    return formField;
  }
}
```

Than I can modify a little bit ErrorResponse and Error classes. Add new constructor and new property textField

```
public class ErrorResponse {

  private Error error;

  ErrorResponse(String errorMessage, int errorCode) {
    createError(errorMessage, errorCode);
  }

  ErrorResponse(String errorMessage, int errorCode, String textField) {
    createError(errorMessage, errorCode, textField);
  }

  private void createError(String message, int code) {
    setError(new Error(message, code));
  }

   private void createError(String message, int code, String textField) {
    setError(new Error(message, code, textField));
  }

  public Error getError() {
    return error;
  }

  public void setError(Error error) {
    this.error = error;
  }

}
```

**Error**

```
public class Error {
  private String message;
  private int code;
  private int String textField;

  public Error(String message, int code) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public Error(String message, int code, String textField) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
    this.textField = textField;
  }

  // setters and getters
}
```

But then I need also create a new Mapper because the old one is made for CustomException and in CustomException there is no textField property.

Is it possible to use somehow one Mapper for all custom exceptions and not create for every custom exception extra mapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common base class for all your custom exception and use Base class in Exception mapper.

Eg:

```
public class MyServiceException extends RuntimeException {

  private ErrorCode errorCode;
  private boolean customMessage;


  public boolean haveCustomMessage() {
    return customMessage;
  }

  public MyServiceException(ErrorCode errorCode) {
    super(errorCode.getMessage());
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  public MyServiceException(ErrorCode errorCode, String msg) {
    super(msg);
    customMessage = true;
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5212119866822715497L;


  public HttpError getHttpError() {

    return new HttpError(errorCode);
  }
}

public class DataNotFoundException extends MyServiceException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public DataNotFoundException() {
    super(ErrorCode.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
  }

}

public class InternalServerException extends MyServiceException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public InternalServerException() {
    super(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }

}

@Provider
public class MyServiceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyServiceException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(MyServiceException exception) {
    return Response.status(exception.getHttpError().getErrorCode().getCode())
        .entity(exception.getHttpError().getErrorCode().getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
  }
}

public class HttpError {

  public HttpError(ErrorCode errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  private ErrorCode errorCode;

  public ErrorCode getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
  }

}

public enum ErrorCode {

  INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(
      Code.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Messages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR), DATA_NOT_FOUND(Code.DATA_NOT_FOUND,
      "Data not found ");


  private int errorCode;
  private String errorMessage;

  private ErrorCode(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }

  private interface Code {

    int DATA_NOT_FOUND = 404;
    int INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 500;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return errorCode;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
  }
}
```